# How to OpenForm using two conditions in macro builder Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am building a database that needs to open a form and fill in all the fields based on two values, Contract Type and P.No but i cannot create the macro that checks the 2 fields before displaying the result.

How can i build a macro that checks both the fields and shows the result accordingly.

The form that has the two fields:

[image]

Underlying macro code:

[image]

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: open using visible property set  =false, check and either close or set visible property = true depending on values

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple issues to clarify: 
* the 2 fields: if the form's data depends on these then where are these fields displaying? ...and what is their source of data?

- how does a user change the values of these 2 fields? - are they linked together so that both get changed at the same time i.e. Last Name First Name - - or are they separate?

I think what you may be seeking is a standard combobox/selector in the header of a form to select the record that is to display....but that will depend on your feedback.